# Adjusting the Sonar BuildBreaker Code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I have been trying for some time to do a maven build on the sonar buildbreaker code that I cloned from github https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker. I am looking to adjust the code, but it won't compile; I have tried troubleshooting for a few weeks. There seems to be no internet answer. Any suggestions on what the issue could be here?

Here's my system details:

Apache Maven 3.3.9 Java version: 1.8.0_92 Windows 7

Here's the error on the maven build:

> [WARNING] Error injecting:
>   org.sonarsource.pluginpackaging.SonarPluginMojo
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) at
>   com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
>   at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162) at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.common.base.Function at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
>   ... 55 more [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 5.431 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-02-17T17:08:10-05:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/360M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.15:sonar-plugin (default-sonar-plugin) on project sonar-build-breaker-plugin:
>   Execution default-sonar-plugin of goal
>   org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.15:sonar-plugin failed: A required class was missing while executing
>   org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.15:sonar-plugin:
>
> ### com/google/common/base/Function [ERROR]

Comment: Please provide the run Maven command line.

Answer (score 0):

The project itself is fine. It runs perfectly on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) and I double checked it locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker.git
cd sonar-build-breaker
mvn verify -B -e -V
```

With an alternate local Maven repository folder (`mvn -Dmaven.repo.local={alternate-repository-folder} verify -B -e -V`) you can make sure that potentially broken dependencies in your default folder (C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2\repository) are not bothering you here.

Comment: It might just be my machine. i went through jar hell and searched every error message possible. Thank you for responding. I will try it on a different machine and see if it works.